# How can i get id of my selected option with vue select

Tags: vue.js, vue-select

I have 2 vue-selects one of users and one of addresses. I need to get the id of what I select so i can send the id to my axios request where I need to compare if User has more than one address and show all of these addresses. I know I need to use v-model on the parent and from the child emit the event but then I'm getting confused how I actually  get the id.

Parent component

```
<template>
    <div>
        <search-infinite
            class="my-2"
            :url="'users'"
            :label="'name'"
            v-model:selectedUser="selectedUser"
        >
        </search-infinite>

        <search-infinite
            :url="'address'"
            :label="'address'"
            v-model:selectedAddress="selectedAddress"

        >
        </search-infinite>

    </div>
</template>

<script>
import SearchInfinite from "./SearchInfinite";

export default {
    name: "Home",
    props:{

    },
    data: () => ({
        url: String,
        label: String,
        selectedUser: "",
        selectedAddress:"",
    }),
    components:{
        SearchInfinite
    },
    methods:{

    }
}
</script>
```

```
<template>
    <v-select
        :options="list"
        :label="label"
        :filterable="false"
        @open="onOpen"
        @close="onClose"
        @search="inputSearch"
        class="form-control"
        :loading="loading"
    >

        <template #list-footer>
            <li v-show="hasNextPage" ref="load" class="loader">
                Loading more options...
            </li>
        </template>
    </v-select>
</template>
<script>
import 'vue-select/dist/vue-select.css';
import _ from "lodash";

export default {

    name: 'Search-Infinite',
    props:{
        url: String,
        label: String,
        selectedAddress:null,
        selectedUser:null,
    },
    data: () => ({
        observer: null,
        limit: 10,
        search: '',
        list: [],
        total: 0,
        page: 0,
        loading: false,
    }),
    computed: {

        hasNextPage() {

            return this.list.length < this.total
        },
    },
    mounted() {
      this.observer = new IntersectionObserver(this.infiniteScroll)
    },
    created() {
        this.getUsers();
    },
    methods: {
        getUsers(search) {

            this.page++;
            axios
                .get(this.url, {

                    params: {
                        search: search,
                        page: this.page,

                    }
                })
                .then((response) => {

                   this.list = this.list.concat(response.data.data);
                    this.total = response.data.total;

                })
                .catch()
                .then(() => {
                    this.loading = false;
                })
        },
        async onOpen() {

               await this.$nextTick()
                this.observer.observe(this.$refs.load)

        },
        onClose() {
          this.observer.disconnect()
        },
        async infiniteScroll([{isIntersecting, target}]) {
            if (isIntersecting) {

                const ul = target.offsetParent
                const scrollTop = target.offsetParent.scrollTop
                this.limit += 10
                this.getUsers();
                await this.$nextTick()
               ul.scrollTop = scrollTop
            }
        },
        inputSearch: _.debounce(   async function (search, loading) {
            if (search.length) {
                this.list = []
                this.loading = true
                this.page = 0
                this.limit += 10
                this.getUsers(search, loading)
                await this.$nextTick()

            }
        }, 500),
    },

}
</script>
```

structure

```
 "data": [
    {
      "id": 1612,
      "name": "Aaliyah Kassulke",
      "email": "vgoyette@example.net",
      "email_verified_at": null,
      "created_at": "2022-05-30T08:45:08.000000Z",
      "updated_at": "2022-05-30T08:45:08.000000Z"
    },
```

Answer (score 3):

On a standard `select` you can set the `value` on each `option` to a nested value which would be returned when selected e.g.

```
<select v-model="selectedUser">
  <option 
    v-for="user in users"
    :key="user.id"
    :value="user.id"
  >
    {{ user.name }} 
  </option> 
</select>
```

There should be a prop related to this for use with the `v-select` in the API documentation, if not, you could just add a separate `computed` value to return just the selected ID, that will update whenever a new user is selected. This is assuming that your `v-select` returns the user object when selected.

```
computed: {
  selectedStudentId() {
    return this.selectedUser?.id;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want only id then you can use reduce function as shown below.  so you can get the direct id of the selected option in the v-model.

```
 <v-select
        :options="list"
        :label="label"
        :reduce="(list) => list.id"
         v-model="userId"
        @change="$emit('your-event',userId)"

    >
```

now, you can listen to event @your-event in parent and get the user id.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a method:

```
<v-select
    :options="list"
    :label="label"
    :reduce="(list) => list.id"
     v-model="userId"
    @change="customerIndexChanged($event)"

>
```

customerIndexedChagned method:

```
 customerIndexChanged(event) {
      const fieldOffice = event.target.options[event.target.options.selectedIndex].text.toLowerCase(); // event.target.value;
      const locationDdlList = `https://api.fbi.gov/wanted/v1/list`;
      const params = {
        'field_offices': `${fieldOffice}`
    }
```

This gets the text of the selected item:

event.target.options[event.target.options.selectedIndex].text

This gets the selected value of the option (the id):

event.target.value

I know, old question...